# React Bootstrap how to prompt user error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using **React-Bootstrap** and currently I am figuring out how to prompt error while user entering the data incorrectly.

For example user login, after the user click *Login Button*, the input text below will show a red mark error example *Username and password does not match

I go for some digging, I have no luck for finding this example, but I do found (required) field, but this is not for my case.

My code as below:

```
<Form>
   <Label>UserName</Label>
       <InputGroup className="mb-3">
             <Input type="text" onChange={this.Username} placeholder="Enter UserName" />
       </InputGroup>
   <Label>Password</Label>
        <InputGroup className="mb-4">
              <Input type="password" onChange={this.Password} placeholder="Enter Password" />
        </InputGroup>
<Form.Control.Feedback type="valid" color="danger" tooltip>*Username and Password Incorrect</Form.Control.Feedback>
          Button onClick={this.Login} color="success" block>Login</Button>
</Form>
```

But it seems like `Form.Control.Feedback` doesnt work.

**Requirements**

1. I am using React Js
2. I am using React-bootstrap library https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/

How should I perform the action I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use `form.checkValidity()` method inside submit button handler?

```js
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    const form = event.currentTarget;
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }

    setValidated(true);
  };
```

Comment: More information here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-validation-native

Comment: and here: https://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_validation_api.asp